# Type polymorphic implicit class compile errors

Tags: scala, types, typeclass, implicit

I'm trying to create a generic builder implicit typeclass for use with generator based tests, as a learning exercise. The example below captures the essential logic. (Instead of combining members of type FooLike, GenBuilder will be used to combine members of scalacheck's Gen trait)

```
object Foo {
    trait FooLike[A] {
        def foo(a: A): String
    }

    object FooLike {
        implicit object FooLikeInt extends FooLike[Int] {
            override def foo(a: Int): String = a.toString
        }
    }

    implicit class GenBuilder[T](self: T)(implicit f: FooLike[T]){

        private var _items = Set(self)

        def |?|(that: GenBuilder[T]): GenBuilder[T] = {
            _items =  _items + that.self
            this
        }

        def items: Set[String] = _items.toSet.map((a: T) => f.foo(a))
    }

}

object Test {
    import Foo._
    import Foo.FooLike._
    def test = {
        val res = 11 |?| 12 |?| 13 |?| 14
        println(res.items)
    }
}


Test.test
```

results in the following compilation error:

```
/Users/pkinsky/genBuilder.scala:19: error: value self is not a member of Main.$anon.Foo.GenBuilder[T]
            _items =  _items + that.self
```

These compiler errors are confusing to me: how can self not be a member of GenBuilder[T]?

(Note: I'm running this as a script using 'scala $filename', if that has any effect on Scala's type system voodoo)

Comment: What if you put `val self: T` in the constructor parameters?

Comment: Oh my god, I'm an idiot. Only case classes auto-expose constructor params without val. This isn't deep type system voodoo, this is the obvious slapping me in the face.

Add this comment as an answer if you want the credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a case of *some deep type system voodoo*, but rather the different way that constructor parameters are used in Scala.

Changing your class header to

```
implicit class GenBuilder[T](val self: T)(implicit f: FooLike[T]){
```

(note the **val** self) will make `self` a field of the `GenBuilder`, rather than just avaliable in the constuctor/privately.

Case classes do this automagically with all of their parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works, somehow. Replacing `that.self` with `that.getSelf` with `def getSelf: T = self` causes it to compile and work, printing `Set(11, 12, 13, 14)` as expected. Coming soon: my next question, where I ask WHY? WHY DOES THIS WORK?

```
object Foo {
    trait FooLike[A] {
        def foo(a: A): String
    }

    object FooLike {
        implicit object FooLikeInt extends FooLike[Int] {
            override def foo(a: Int): String = a.toString
        }
    }

    implicit class GenBuilder[T](self: T)(implicit f: FooLike[T]){

        private var _items = Set(self)
        def getSelf: T = self

        def |?|(that: GenBuilder[T]): GenBuilder[T] = {
            that.getSelf
            _items =  _items + that.getSelf
            this
        }

        def items: Set[String] = _items.toSet.map((a: T) => f.foo(a))
    }

}

object Test {
    import Foo._
    import Foo.FooLike._
    def test = {
        val res = 11 |?| 12 |?| 13 |?| 14
        println(res.items)
    }
}


Test.test
```